# How to secure web service methods using tokenization for Facebook logins?

Tags: ios, facebook, web-services, security, soap

In my application, each user will have his/her own login credentials by signing up. To secure their personal informations, we are using tokenization method. ie, while login after  giving username and password, we'll create a dynamic token for that user. Using that token we'll fetch the user's details from the server though out the application.

But, for Facebook login(iOS 6.0 sdk), we just have the username(email address) we can't get any passwords from the user. If we provide a token for a user by just passing the email address to the web method means, it won't be a secured one. What to do with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [User Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) which will be received from Facebook once the User gave the permissions to the application.

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but why did you have to edit my answer?

Comment: Your answer was like a comment. So, I've edited it and added the link to developer site documentation.

Comment: Yeah, but you change the subject of the sentence, so it's not really what I said originally. Well, nevermind... Great that you found a solution